# Regex to match a hyphenated and non hyphenated word simultaneously

Tags: php, regex

Hi I have the following string:

```
e-bgp-ip@2016-03-21.y:688: error: bad value "redi-bfg" (should be if-feat-ex)
```

I need to match the string with a regex. However the string can be hyphenated and non-hyphenated so it can also be

```
e-bgp-ip@2016-03-21.y:688: error: bad value "redibfg" (should be if-feat-ex)
```

I can catch the non-hyphenated version with

```
/^.*? error: bad value \"\w+\" \(should be *.*$/m
```

I'm trying to replace any line this regex matches, heres an example I have for a different line:

```
$line = preg_replace('/^.*? key \"\w+\" not in order, *.*$/m', '', $line);
```

However I need a regex that can catch both the first example and the second example, anyone have any ideas how I can do this?

Comment: Use `\S+` (non-whitespace) instead of `\w+` (word).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just replace `\w` by a character class that includes the dash: `[\w-]`

```
$line = preg_replace('/^.*? key "[\w-]+" not in order, *.*$/m', '', $line);
```

Comment: I would suggest to place the `-` directly after the opening square bracket to avoid unintentional creating of character ranges.

Comment: @syck: Are you saying one should *not* put it at the end, like Toto did?

Comment: To have the hyphen interpreted as it is, you have to place it either at the beginning or at the end; if it is placed in between characters, it is interpreted as range operator (like in `[a-z]`). Suppose sometimes you have to allow some other characters too, like @ or + or anything else. `[$-,]` would constitute a valid character range (same as `[$%&'()*+,]`), but is maybe not what you want. So I usually propose to make a habit of placing the hyphen at the beginning of the class. Just my two cents to avoid hard-to-find bugs.